# Oracle APEX, design overview and suggestions

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to ORACLE APEX

If I want to make a layout like this on ORACLE APEX, where I will have a  say specfic name of script that I want to display all the information relating to the that particular script like it's server info, database info, contacts info in to 3 sections like below. All 3 sections are tables on a ERD ,normalized

What do you suggest as far as what i should pick like report or blank page, just looking for an overview of what i should do, each sections will be queried and displayed.

```
                      ORACLE APEX PAGE
```

---

Please Enter name of script: |***_*__*_*__*_*___**|

__*_*____*SERVER INFORMATION****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

SERVER NAME

LIST

Run  TIME

REST TIME

__*_*____*DATABASE INFORMATION****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

DATABASE NAME

DATABASE CYCLE TIME

DATABASE NUMBER

HOSTNAME

__*_*__*_*__*_**CONTACTS****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly that format, I would expect that you'd start with a blank page.  Add four regions, one for the search controls, one for the server information, one for the database information, and one for the contacts.  Add the text fields to each region.  I'm not sure if you want to add a report to the Contacts region or if you're going to add more text fields there.  And then add a process that goes off and populates the data based on the script field when the page is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to display the data and not have it enterable, you may be best of by using classic reports. While you usually use them to display rows of data in a table, their markup is steered by templates. There are some default report templates which will allow you to display the data in key-value pairs.
Your page will be a lot easier to maintain in this way, and you won't need to fiddle around with page items and their session state.
**Note:** report templates <> region templates! The former is the template of the report itself, of the data structure, while the latter controls the layout of the region as a whole, encapsulating the report.
In apex 4.2 (and previous, though the section may be named differently) you can control the report template of a classic report by editing the **report attributes**, and under the "Layout and pagination" section you can set the "Report template". For example, in Theme 24 there is a template called "Value Attribute Pairs".

Just have the search region with some controls on it. For example, if all you really need is one item to hold the name of the script you could call it `P1_SCRIPT_NAME`. In the reports you then need to reference this in the where-clause.
Then you'll need the reports, which will be three regions and 3 thus 3 classic reports. You can steer the region's look and feel with templates too!
The page will then need to be submitted to refresh the regions.
Or alternatively -and this is a great thing about using reports- you can dodge the full submit and simply refresh the 3 regions by using a Dynamic Action. If you do this, don't forget to set the "Page items to submit" option on the 3 reports to the name of the page items included in the where clause, so that they will fetch the correct data!